# SAS: What is the quickest way to convert a dataset compressed in binary to compressed using char or vice versa?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset sitting on a local drive and I would like to convert it to char compress from binary compressed (or vice versa).

```
data local.dataset1(compress=c);
  set local.dataset1;
run;
```

This is the best way I know. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single data set with no indices, yes, I would consider your data step the best way to rebuild the file.

From the [COMPRESS= documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lesysoptsref&docsetTarget=n0uhpz2l79vy0qn12x3ifcvjzsyt.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) Details section

> Once a file is compressed, the setting is a permanent attribute of the file, which means that to change the setting, you must re-create the file. That is, to uncompress a file, specify COMPRESS=NO for a DATA step that copies the compressed file.

In your case, you are not uncompressing but recompressing with a different compression option (i.e. algorithm)

For the case of very large > 1/2 disk filling data sets you might get an error while rebuilding the data set -- you would need to move the original file to separate disk before rebuilding it with the different compression in the `local` library.

For the case of a data set with meta-data such as a label, passwords, generations and indices, you might want to use Proc DATASETS, COPY statement with NOCLONE option.